# Where to find the X-GNOME-* keys documentation for .desktop files

Tags: 20.04, gnome, xdg

I've searched the net with no luck trying to find the documentation for the extended X-GNOME-* keys used into the .desktop files.

can anyone point me to such documentation?

Thanks